# PerformanceCounter multiple Processes

Tags: vb.net, process, wmi

I'm building a fast process cpu usage detection program and I'm getting a little issue here with PerformanceCounter.

If i add a PerformanceCounter object and put the right values on the properties separator on GUI I have this working. But this work just for 1 fixed process. So what I'm trying to do is a dynamic way to get the values.
Look:

```
Private Function getCPUByProcessName(ByVal proc As String) as Single
        Return New PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", proc).NextValue()
End Function
```

This function must return the % and it doesn't. If I try to get a fixed process % cpu usage by coding on the class It doesn't work. But if I just go to the GUI and add from toolbox and edit the properties to contribute to the laziness it works. :/

TL;DR: the function above doesn't work. returns always 0.0

CORRECTED CODE:

```
Public ProcDic As New Dictionary(Of Integer, PerformanceCounter)

Private Function getCPUByProcess(ByRef proc As Process) As Single
        If Not ProcDic.ContainsKey(proc.Id) Then
            ProcDic.Add(proc.Id, New PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time",proc.ProcessName))
        End If
        Return ProcDic.Item(proc.Id).NextValue()
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That cannot work, you *must* use the exact same PerformanceCounter object to get a reliable value for NextValue().  Right now you create a new one every time so it always starts from scratch.  And NextValue will always be 0.  It needs to stay around to collect history.

Just use a `Dictionary(Of Integer, PerformanceCounter)` to keep track of existing counters.  Use the Process.Id property as the key.